# How to store a JsonArray in a Map?

Tags: java, json

I have used the following Code

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new  JSONArray(incomingData);

    Map<String,String> map=new HashMap<String,String>();

    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
         JSONObject j = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
         Iterator<?> it = j.keys();
         while (it.hasNext()) {
              String n =  it.next().toString();
              map.put(n, j.getString(n));
           }
    }
```

But when I execute this code it's throwing an Exception.

```
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["low_stock_date"] not a string.
```

JsonArray Used

```
[
  {
    "item_id": "1",
    "product_id": "1",
    "stock_id": "1",
    "qty": "99.0000",
    "low_stock_date": null
  },
  {
    "item_id": "2",
    "product_id": "2",
    "stock_id": "1",
    "qty": "100.0000",
    "low_stock_date": null
  }
]
```

Please help me to over come this issue.

Comment: Can you share your JSON array content.

Comment: I have shared the JsonArray.

Comment: At which line exception is coming? You will get it from stacktrace.

Comment: At   this line String n =  it.next().toString();

Comment: can you print String `n` and check what values it carries when you iterate.

Comment: try casting with `String` instead of using `toString()` method

Comment: It is Printing only two values.                                                                                        product_id
low_stock_date

Comment: Why are you trying to put all the fields of all the elements of an array into the same map? What is your desired result for your code?

Comment: @DanGetz, Actually i need  All the product_id values from the JSONArray and store it in a Array.

Comment: But you have no arrays or lists in your code...and if you just need the `product_id` values, what's the map for? Are you trying to store a map from `product_id` → something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `low_stock_date` is `null`. thats why it is throwing this error.

Just add one check for `null` before adding it into Map.

```
if(!j.isNull(n)){
        map.put(n, j.getString(n));
}
else{
        map.put(n, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
     JSONObject j = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
     Iterator<?> it = j.keys();
     while (it.hasNext()) {
          String n =  it.next().toString();
          map.put(n, j.getString(n));
       }
}
```

You are doing the above, inside for loop & storing the key/value pair in Map. 
As same  keys are there in every `JSONObject` so only values in last jsonobject would be there in for Map keys.
As an alternate you can create an `ArrayList` for storing these Maps, which you can get while converting each `JSONObject` to `Map`

One more thing you can do here is using a parser like [Jackson Parser](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes)

`HashMap<String,String> result =
        new ObjectMapper().readValue(JSON_SOURCE, HashMap.class);`
(where JSON_SOURCE is a File, input stream, reader, or json content String).

That would be quick & better way of doing the what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually how the method is implemented:

```
/**
 * Get the string associated with a key.
 *
 * @param key
 *            A key string.
 * @return A string which is the value.
 * @throws JSONException
 *             if there is no string value for the key.
 */
public String getString(String key) throws JSONException {
    Object object = this.get(key);
    if (object instanceof String) {
        return (String) object;
    }
    throw new JSONException("JSONObject[" + quote(key) + "] not a string.");
}
```

You could check the type of the to-be-loaded object to see if it is null:

```
j.isNull(n);
```

and then act accordingly:

```
if (j.isNull(n)) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```